# Relations on Surjective Functions

Tags: functions, logic, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $f:A\to B$ be a surjective function. I am asked to find a relation $R$ such that

$\bar{f}: A/R \to B$

$[a]\mapsto \bar{f}([a]) = f(a)$

My thoughts on this problem are that, for $\bar{f}$ to be well defined, it cannot depend on the representative *i.e.* if $[a]=[b]$ then $\bar{f}([a]) = \bar{f}([b])$. But I don't know how to keep going.

I have defined $R$ to be $aRb \iff f(a) = f(b)$. I have also proved that $R$ is an equivalence relation, but I don't know how to prove the $\bar{f}$, with $R$ defined like this, is bijective. Does anyone know how?

Comment: You have asked this [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965908/surjective-functions-and-relations).  As before, I expect that you are meant to find $R$ such that $\overline f:A/R\to B$ is a bijection.  Absent that condition, the problem is trivial. Let $R$ be the most basic equivalence relation, namely, $a_1\sim a_2\iff a_1=a_2$.  Then $A/R=A$ so there is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\bar f$, defined by $\bar f\bigl([a]\bigr)=f(a)$ is injective by construction, and it is not hard to check that it is surjective because $f$ is by  hypothesis.

Comment: But how can I prove it is injective?

Comment: For me it is obvious: all elements of $A$ which have the same image in $B$ are in the same equivalence class. Put more formally,  $f\bigl([a]\bigr)=f\bigl([b]\bigr)$ means $f(a)=f(b)$, so $aRb$, and ultimately $[a]=[b]$.